# Channel Entries Month Without Year?

Tags: channel, entries

I'm trying to display all entries in certain months without caring about what year it's in. Currently the tag looks like (for February as an example):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:listingchannel}" month="2" show_future_entries="yes" dynamic="no" orderby="entry_date" sort="asc"}
```

However it only shows entries from 2016 and not 2017. How could I make it pull in entries from future years?

Bit of context: I'm putting an event calendar on a website. Some events listed are for the next year and I still want them to show even though it's not that year yet. It needs to be dynamic so I don't have to go in and update years every month to grab the future events that are listed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with current scenario of ExpressionEngine Channel entries tag. You can create small plugin (pi file) to manage this.

Let me know if you are new in this and don't know to create plugin. I can create one for you.